# Build a “feature card board with highest portfolioitem as the swimlanes” - how to deal with rowConfig?

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I am trying to build a Feature rallycardboard group by the HighestPortfoilioItem and I am unable to create the desired swimlane. What should be the rowConfig for later added fields?

```
_load: function (store, records) {
    var me = this;
    _.each(records, function (record) {
       //trying to add the product to create the swimlane
        record.set('HigestPorfolioItem', me.FeaturePorfolioValueMap[record.data.ObjectID]);
    });
    this._addBoard();
},
_addBoard: function () {
    var me = this;
    me.add({
        xtype: 'rallycardboard',
        types: ['PortfolioItem/Feature', 'PortfolioItem/product'],
        attribute: 'ScheduleState',
        context: this.getContext(),
        enableRanking: false,
        rowConfig: {
            field:'HigestPorfolioItem'
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: This is an interesting one.  Can you give a little more info?  How many levels do you have in your PI hierarchy?  My initial reaction is that it will probably be tough to do this...

Comment: Kyle,We have 3 level (Featues,Epic and Product).Features are associated with Epic and Epic with Products. I am trying to create a product swimlane for its assoicated Features.